# How to convert this non-tail-recursion function to a loop or a tail-recursion version?

Tags: python, recursion, tail-recursion

I've been curious for this for long. It is really very easy and elegant for human to create a non-tail-recursive function to get something complicated, but the speed is very slow and easily hit the limit of Python recursion:

```
def moves_three(n, ini=0, med=1, des=2):
    '''give a int -> return a list '''
    if n == 1:
        return ((ini,des),)
    return moves_three(n-1, ini=ini, med=des, des=med) + \
           ((ini, des),) + \
           moves_three(n-1, ini=med, med=ini, des=des)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    moves_three(100) # may be after several hours you can see the result.
    len(moves_three(10000))
```

So, how to change `moves_three` to a tail recursion one or a loop (better)? More important, are there any essays to talk about this? Thanks.

Comment: [Python doesn't do tail optimization](http://neopythonic.blogspot.in/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html), so don't bother making a tail recursive version :)

Comment: @thefourtheye thanks I know that. Python have ways to TCO, I know two ways, so both is OK...

Comment: @thefourtheye But they can be [made iterative](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/decorator/documentation3.html#dealing-with-third-party-decorators), solving the recursion problem. :)

Comment: @Schoolboy There isn't much point in using a decorator. The conversion to a loop is absolutely trivial that it wouldn't take much time to refactor the function into a loop, which would also avoid all the overhead of the decorator and of the function-calls.

Comment: @Bakuriu Yes, most tail-recursive functions can be converted to loops.. And the decorator is just an example that I found interesting...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even with an iterative form, this isn't going to get any faster. The problem isn't the recursion limit; you're still an order of magnitude below the recursion limit. The problem is that the size of your output is `O(2^n)`. For `n=100`, you have to build a tuple of about a thousand billion billion billion elements. It doesn't matter how you build it; you'll never finish.

If you want to convert this to iteration anyway, that can be done by managing state with an explicit stack instead of the call stack:

```
def moves_three(n, a=0, b=1, c=2):
    first_entry = True
    stack = [(first_entry, n, a, b, c)]
    output = []
    while stack:
        first_entry, n1, a1, b1, c1 = stack.pop()
        if n1 == 1:
            output.append((a1, c1))
        elif first_entry:
            stack.append((False, n1, a1, b1, c1))
            stack.append((True, n1-1, a1, c1, b1))
        else:
            output.append((a1, c1))
            stack.append((True, n1-1, b1, a1, c1))
    return tuple(output)
```

Confusing, isn't it? A tuple `(True, n, a, b, c)` on the stack represents entering a function call with arguments `n, a, b, c`. A tuple `(False, n, a, b, c)` represents returning to the `(True, n, a, b, c)` call after `moves_three(n-1, a, c, b)` ends.

Comment: Thank you very much. I make a yield version of your answer, so even it is very huge, it can still output.