# Python 3.3 How to convert this recursive function to a pure yield loop version?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, recursion

My question comes from a variant of Hanoi, which has four towers.

I know [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418776/How-to-replace-recursive-functions-using-stack-and) which says In c++ you can convert any recursive function to a loop, but I am only familiar with Python. I tried to read the ten rules but what do the keywords `struct` and `stack` means to python?

So, any article or discuss for python which is similar to the C++ one above is also very appreciated. Thanks.

---

The raw recursive function is `fmove` (holds another recursive function `tmove`), receives an integer, returns a tuple of pairs. It is elegant but useless (try `tmove(100)` and be careful of your memory).

I want to convert it to a pure yield loop version so even the n becomes big like 100 or 1000, I can still know what the first 10 or 100 pairs of the tuple is.

```
def memory(function):
    """
    This is a decorator to help raw recursion
    functions to avoid repetitive calculation.
    """
    cache = {}
    def memofunc(*nkw,**kw):
        key=str(nkw)+str(kw)
        if key not in cache:            
            cache[key] = function(*nkw,**kw)
        return cache[key]
    return memofunc

@memory 
def tmove(n, a=0, b=1, c=2):
    "int n -> a tuple of pairs"
    if n==1:
        return ((a,c),)
    return tmove(n-1,a,c,b)+\
           ((a,c),)+\
           tmove(n-1,b,a,c)

@memory        
def fmove(n,a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3):
    "int n -> a tuple of pairs"
    if n==1:
        return ((a,d),)
    return min(
        (
            fmove(n-i,a,d,b,c) +
            tmove(i,a,b,d) +
            fmove(n-i,c,b,a,d)
            for i in range(1,n)
        ),
        key=len,)
```

With the help of user2357112 in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952770/python-3-3-how-to-convert-this-non-tail-recursion-function-to-a-loop-or-a-tail-r), I know how to convert recursive functions like `tmove` -- return recur(...)+ CONS or another call +recur(...), but when situations getting more complicated like `fmove`, I don't know how to design the structure, -- the `i` is relevant to `n` which is different in a different stack, and you finally have to use `min` to get the minimum size tuple as the correct output for the current stack.

This is my try (the core algorithm `best(n)`is still recursive function):

```
@memory        
def _best(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1,1
    return min(
        (
            (i, 2*(_best(n-i)[1])+2**i-1)
            for i in range(1,n)
        ),
        key=lambda x:x[1],
    )

def best(n):
    return _best(n)[0]

def xtmove(n,a=0,b=1,c=2):
    stack = [(True,n,a,b,c)]
    while stack:
        tag,n,a,b,c = stack.pop()
        if n==1:
            yield a,c
        elif tag:
            stack.append((False,n,a,b,c))
            stack.append((True,n-1,a,c,b))
        else:
            yield a,c
            stack.append((True,n-1,b,a,c))

def xfmove(n,a=0,b=1,c=2,d=3):
    stack = [(True,n,a,b,c,d)]
    while stack:
        is_four,n,a,b,c,d = stack.pop()
        if n==1 and is_four:
            yield a,d
        elif is_four:
            # here I use a none-tail-recursion function 'best'
            # to get the best i, so the core is still not explicit stack.
            i = best(n) 
            stack.append((True,n-i,c,b,a,d))
            stack.append((False,i,a,b,d,None))
            stack.append((True,n-i,a,d,b,c))
        else:
            for t in xtmove(n,a,b,c):
                yield t
```

This is the test code. Make sure you can pass it.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    MAX_TEST_NUM = 20
    is_passed = all((
                fmove(test_num) == tuple(xfmove(test_num))
                for test_num in range(1,MAX_TEST_NUM)
              ))
    assert is_passed, "Doesn't pass the test."
    print("Pass the test!")
```

Comment: Unless you're converting something that uses tail recursion, you're going to end up just simulating recursion with a stack and a loop. You rarely need to do this, so is this just an exercise to see if you *can* do it? If so, I'd do it in a language you know, first, or by porting the recursive version to C++.

Comment: IMO what you need is a dynamic programming approach in which you build the DP matrix from bottom up. This may or may not reduce your memory usage significantly depending on whether you can discard some of the DP matrix entries that are no longer needed. You can google for recursive vs DP approach to problem solving. As regards your question about C++ struct, it is similar to Python class (I think, I am not much conversant with Python)

Comment: @David Ehrmann That would be great if you make a Python version :).This is not an exercise, however, this is coming from an exercise. I am not satisfied with my current solution. I am interested in it. I also feel that if I know some generic skills to covert recursive function to loop or yield loop in Python just like that C++ article, my ability to solve complicated problems will rise.

Comment: @Abhishek Bansal Thanks, I will see that.

Answer (score 1):

`fmove` performs a `min` over all the values of its recursive calls and the call to `tmove` so there can be no streaming of results in this case. You need 100% of the calls to finish to get the result of `min`.

Regarding the stack approach, it is creating a minimal interpreter with 2 opcodes, True and False. :)

Look how tmove can stream results without recurring to archaic techniques necessary in languages without generators.

```
from itertools import chain

def xtmove(n, a=0, b=1, c=2):
    "int n -> a tuple of pairs"
    if n==1:
        yield (a,c)
    else:
        for i in chain(xtmove(n-1,a,c,b), [(a,c)], xtmove(n-1,b,a,c)):
            yield i
```

Answer (score 0):

After days of study, with the help of the c++ article, I finally get the pure loop version by myself. And I think @Javier is right -- it is impossible to yield.

```
def best(n):
    """
    n -> best_cut_number 
    four-towers Hanoi best cut number for n disks.
    """
    stacks = [(0,n,[],None,)] #(stg,n,possible,choice)
    cache={1:(1,0)} 
    while stacks:
        stg,n,possible,choice=stacks.pop()
        if n in cache:
            res = cache[n]
        elif stg==0:
            stacks.append((1,n,possible,n-1))
            stacks.append((0,1,[],None))
        else:
            value = 2*res[0] + 2**choice-1
            possible.append((value,choice))
            if choice > 1:
                stacks.append((1,n,possible,choice-1))
                stacks.append((0,n-choice+1,[],None))
            else:
                res = min(possible,key=lambda x:x[0])
                cache[n] = res
    best_cut_number = res[1]
    return best_cut_number
```